# Google Calendar API как сделать авторизацию в дестоп приложении C#

Tags: c#, wpf, google-calendar-api

Нужно что-бы каждый экземпляр приложения был уникальным при попытке подключится к google Calendar API и у меня проблема с тем что соединение хранится даже при выключении приложения и я не могу найти возможности выйти из аккаунта с помощью своего приложения. Пользовался данной литературой

1. https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth
2. https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/reference/1.10.0/classGoogle_1_1Apis_1_1Auth_1_1OAuth2_1_1UserCredential#a0d69482e707af645042d4f656231c02e
3. https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/reference/1.10.0/classGoogle_1_1Apis_1_1Util_1_1Store_1_1FileDataStore

Код для авторизации

```
        string[] Scopes = { CalendarService.Scope.Calendar };
        string ApplicationName = "Google Calendar API .NET fghj";


        UserCredential credential;

        using (var stream =
            new FileStream("credentials.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {

            string credPath = "token.json";
            credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                Scopes,
                "user",
                CancellationToken.None,
                new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;
            Console.WriteLine("Credential file saved to: " + credPath);
        }


        service = new CalendarService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = credential,
            ApplicationName = ApplicationName,
        });
```